# Apache Tomcat v8.5 icon missing from list in Eclipse's New Server Run Time Environment

Tags: eclipse, java-8, sapui5, tomcat8

Here is the information about my Development Environment:

- -Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.(Version: Neon Release (4.6.0))
    (Build id: 20160613-1800)
- -Java SE Dev Kit 8u102
- -JRE 1.8.0_102
- Trial version SAP HANA Cloud Platform Cockpit

Please forgive me if the question sounds naive but I'm been a .NET Developer for past few years, and I'm trying to learn SAP Hana Cloud technology.

I've learned that you have to develop code on Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers in order deploy to the Trial version SAP HANA Cloud Platform

I was trying to use Tomcat 8.5 in my local development environment.

[image]

How can I add the the Apache Tomcat v8.5 icon taht is missing from the list within the "New Server Run Time Environment"?

Answer (score 1):

The version of Eclipse WTP that supports Tomcat 8.5 is not out yet and is expected in the 1st maintenance release.

If you need it sooner, you can find instructions on how to get it to run in this bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494936